# lag in cookie updating

Tags: php, cookies

I'm having toruble with this basic cookie script.

There seems to be a lag in the cookie info updating.

Here is the code:

```
$year = time() + (1 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60); // this adds one year to the current time,  for the cookie expiration
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'- 2 days'));
setcookie("lastonline", $time, $year);

echo '<p><p><p>cookie set to '.$time;

$cookietime = $_COOKIE['lastonline'];

echo '<p>Cookie says '.$cookietime;
```

My problem, I run this script with the $time var set to - 1 day, then change this to - 2 days, the report says 'cookie set to (2 days ago) - Cookie says (1 day ago).

If I refresh the script a second time it all comes out corrently, i.e. 'cookie set to (2 days ago) - Cokie says (2 days ago), but why the lag or second refresh needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `setcookie()` call requests the client to store a cookie. That cookie is only sent back to the server *in the context of the next request* sent to the server, whilst you try to evaluate it inside the same script run executing the `setcookie()`. That cannot work, since in that script run you are evaluating the `$_COOKIE` storage which was filled by the *previous* request to the server which only just triggered your script run!

This explains the one-reload-off difference.

This is not a bug or anything, your logic is wrong.